# Trying to convert a simple OBJC fucntion to Swift

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have a simple function in OBJ C to create a random number

```
+(NSString*)certRef
{

NSInteger rNumber = arc4random() % 100000000 + 1;
NSString *randomCertRef = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)rNumber];

return randomCertRef;
}
```

Now im trying to convert it Swift:

Class ToolsCustomFunctions

```
func randomNumber(theNumber: String){

    let rNumber = arc4random() % 100000000 + 1;
    let rNumberString = "\(rNumber)"
    println("THE RANDOM NUMBER IS: \(rNumberString)")

   return (theNumber)

}
```

The above gives Error "string not convertible to ()

Then im trying access it in class B

```
    let rNumberFuction = ToolsCustomFunctions()
    //read randomised number string here//
```

Various attempts including `println "the random number is \(rNumberFuction.randomNumber(theNumber: String))"` result in not accessing/setting the randomised number from my function either through compiler error or a nil value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func randomNumber(theNumber: String) { ... }
```

is a function

- taking one argument (a String), and
- returning nothing (aka `Void` or `()`.

What you want is a function

- without arguments, and
- returning a string

which is declared as

```
func randomNumber() -> String { ... }
```

And the return value should be `rNumberString`, not `theNumber`.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense now on the construction of the function.   However I still cant retrieve the random number in my view/class let rNumberFuction = ToolsCustomFunctions()
        println; "the random number is \(rNumberFuction.randomNumber())"  Error "resolves an unused function"

Comment: @JSA986: Your function is called `randomNumber`, so `let randomString = randomNumber()` should work. What is `ToolsCustomFunctions` ??

Comment: `ToolsCustomFunctions` is a class with functions/managers, so in ANOTHER view im trying to retrieve the resulting number.  In objC I would use `self.someText.text = [randomNumber myrandomNumberFunc];`

Comment: @JSA986: Then `self.someText.text = ToolsCustomFunctions.randomNumber()` might be what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes something just like that, but its "missing argument for a parameter #1 in call"

Comment: @JSA986: Your ObjC function is a *class method*. The Swift analogue is `class func randomNumber() -> String { ... }`.